# O que é um verbo defectivo?

Tags: verbos-defectivos

Quais são as características que tornam um verbo defectivo?

Qual a diferença dele para um verbo regular?

Comment: This sounds like you're setting an exam question, not like you're actually interested in the answer. You look like a native speaker. Do you really not know the answer? Can you maybe ask a more specific question, which can't be answered by copy/paste from the first Google result of `verbo defectivo`?

Comment: @Earthliŋ not sure whether "not knowing the answer" is a pre requisite for asking questions here. Do you think so?

Comment: No, I just don't think it's a good idea to populate this site by posting "common questions", because if you _don't_ know the answer you might ask a better question.

Comment: I think that most of the common questions are valuable to transient people that find the questions on Google, meanwhile interesting and unusual questions are often more useful (or maybe fun) for the community members and have lower value to visitors that are not interested in be part of the community. So that's why I asked who is our [target audience](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/31/3). Actually, I believe that we have space for both.

Comment: @Math I, too, think we have space for both. But we could just wait until someone visits this site and asks these questions out of their own curiosity, rather than posting them pre-emptively.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I think that you idea works nice on paper, but how and when will someone will come with this exact legit doubt? Perhaps we will wait forever and nobody will come up with this kind of questions here. In the other hand when we ask these kind of questions here we improve the site visibility in Google search results, attracting more audience. I don't want to force my point of view, I'm just sharing it, feel free to disagree :)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Does it still look like an "exam question"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Todos os verbos regulares de cada conjugação são conjugados da mesma forma. Isso significa que se você pegar todas as conjugações de um verbo regular A e trocar o radical de A pelo radical de um outro verbo regular B da mesma conjugação, você vai obter como resultado todas as conjugações do verbo regular B. Exemplos de verbos regulares são:

- Na primeira conjugação: [comprar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-comprar), [lutar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-lutar), [ressaltar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-ressaltar), [cantar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-cantar);
- Na segunda conjugação: [vender](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-vender), [bater](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-bater), [comer](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-comer), [dever](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-dever);
- Na terceira conjugação: [decidir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-decidir), [inquirir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-inquirir), [desistir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-desistir), [partir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-partir).

Já com os verbos irregulares, a regra acima não funciona, pois algumas (e por vezes até todas) as formas em que eles são conjugados desviam da forma regular de conjugação. Exemplos de verbos irregulares são:

- Na primeira conjugação: [estar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-estar), [conjugar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-conjugar), [atacar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-atacar);
- Na segunda conjugação: [trazer](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-trazer), [entrever](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-entrever), [ver](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-ver), [ser](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-ser), [pôr](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-p%C3%B4r);
- Na terceira conjugação: [sair](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-sair), [imbuir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-imbuir), [rugir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-rugir).

Um verbo defectivo* é um verbo que não pode ser conjugado em todas as formas possíveis, seja porque a conjugação simplesmente não existe ou porque ela soa muito estranha e sem sentido. Entretanto, para alguns o que pode parecer ser uma conjugação pra lá de estranha, para outros pode ser normal, então há verbos que alguns consideram como defectivos enquanto que outros não os consideram assim, e portanto o conceito de defectivo é um pouco subjetivo. Exemplos de verbos defectivos são:

- Na primeira conjugação: [soar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-soar), [adequar](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-adequar);
- Na segunda conjugação: [reaver](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-reaver), [doer](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-doer), [feder](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-feder);
- Na terceira conjugação: [abolir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-abolir), [exaurir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-exaurir), [demolir](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-demolir).

Em especial, por que esses verbos são defectivos? Vamos tentar conjugá-los em algumas frases:

> Eu acho que eu **soo** muito estranho ao empregar o verbo "soar" na primeira pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo.

> Que eu me **adeque** em considerar o verbo "adequar" como não-defectivo.

> Nós reavemos uma boa conjugação, mas ainda assim, eu **reavo** uma que não existe.

> Eles **doeriam** em saber que eu **fedo** de conjugar verbos de forma tão estranha.

> Tu abolistes o mal uso da linguagem, mas eu **abulo** o bom uso ao conjugar verbos de forma muito estranha. E meu primo também **abole** que nem eu.

> Tu **demoles** a boa língua portuguesa com tais estapafúrdias conjugações, mas por favor, não **exaura** ela!

Percebas, que tais conjugações acima soam erradas e muito esquisitas, pois tratam-se de conjugações verbais aonde verbos defectivos estão a ser conjugados em contextos para os quais não têm conjugação apropriada (ou que pelo menos não pareça ser muito esquisita).

Por fim, há de se notar que os verbos da primeira conjugação tendem a ser mais regulares do que os da segunda e da terceira, e por tal motivo é mais difícil de se encontrar verbos irregulares e defectivos na primeira conjugação do que nas outras duas. Em especial, a maioria dos verbos defectivos está na terceira conjugação.

E para completar, alguns links que me ajudaram muito a elaborar esta resposta:

- http://www.conjuga-me.net/
- http://www.mundoeducacao.com/gramatica/verbos-defectivos.htm
- http://conversadeportugues.com.br/2011/08/verbos-defectivos/

<sup>* A palavra "defectivo" significa "com defeito", e neste caso o verbo defectivo realmente é um verbo com defeito, vez que não pode ser conjugado em todas as formas possíveis.</sup>

Comment: +1 muito bacana a resposta :D

Comment: Alguns outros exemplos incluem *chover* e *nevar* por um lado, e *falir* e *florir* por outro.

Comment: Algumas dessas variações entretanto são extremamente comuns na linguagem falada do Brasil. "Adeque" chega até a ser usado em jornais escritos.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, é exatamente por isso que alguns deles a "defecticidade" (essa palavra existe?) é um tanto subjetiva e depende muito de quem lê ou ouve. Além disso, a língua portuguesa muda com o tempo, então algumas conjugações antes consideradas bizarras passam a ser aceitas e outras outrora aceitas passam a ser consideradas antiquadas.

Comment: Escreve-se "aboliste".